# Problem with concurrent access file in java

Tags: java, concurrency, wildfly

i have a monolith application running in wildfly. This application has a part that reads and retrieves a file and attach it to the http response. This operation is separated in two parts like this:

retrieve a File object reference

```
public File retrieveFile(String path) throws ServiceException, FileNotFoundException {
            String fileLocation = // some calculated location based on the path parameter;
            File file = new File(fileLocation);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            return file;
    }
```

and append the file to the response

```
private void attachFileToResponse(final File file, final String format, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(file);
            if ("pdf".equals(format)) {
                response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
                final OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
                int bytes;
                while ((bytes = input.read()) != -1) {
                    output.write(bytes);
                }
            } else {
                final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
                ImageIO.write(image, format, response.getOutputStream());
            }
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } finally {
                    input = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am facing some problems with these servlet. When an access to an image occurs at the same time (difference in milliseconds) the access to the second image gives an error like this:

```
2022-07-17 21:21:00,600 INFO  [com.myapp.BaseServlet] (default task-8) MyServlet: requesting file: /files/location/1.png
2022-07-17 21:21:00,941 INFO  [com.myapp.BaseServlet] (default task-3) MyServlet: requesting file: /files/location/1.png
2022-07-17 21:21:00,967 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-8) UT005023: Exception handling request to /files/location/1.png: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.seek(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:170)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.close(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:231)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1590)
.......................
```

I am thinking about adding the keyword synchronized to the second method (attachFileToResponse) but i don't know if that is the best way to solve the problem or if it is even going to solve it

Any ideas / suggestions will be very appreciated

Comment: It's not clear why this is happening.  If these methods are called within a servlet environment method (i.e. `doPost` or `doGet`) there shouldn't be an issue.  However, if you're sharing a buffer somewhere there may be a collision.  Additionally, it's not clear why you're bothering with ImageIO - you just want to write the file to the response output stream - why not just do roughly the same as you're doing with the PDF files?

Comment: supposedly ImageIO is better suited to process images, but you may have a point, i should just do the same thing for any type of file